# SetVisibility button in listview SimpleCursorAdapter?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a model_list_view.xml like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lnImprimir"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1.3"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonSimNaoCozinha"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:textSize="1sp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:background="@drawable/lista_anotacoes"
        android:typeface="sans"/>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lnQuantidade"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1.2"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewQuantidade"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:typeface="sans" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lnDescricao"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.80"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewDescricao"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:typeface="sans" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewValor"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:typeface="sans" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The buttonSimNaoCozinha where I want it to appear only when it is **YES** inside the ListView that I did like this.
But this form I set up is not working, according to the code below:

```
private void criarListagem() {
    /**
     * Busca os dados do seu método
     */
    db.buscarDadosComanda(objComanda); /// Metodo de busca

    /**
     * Passa os valores
     */
    String[] from = {
            "imprimir",
            "quantidade",
            "descricao",
            "valor"}; // nome dos campos da tabela
    int[] to = {
            R.id.buttonSimNaoCozinha,
            R.id.textViewQuantidade,
            R.id.textViewDescricao,
            R.id.textViewValor}; // Nome dos campos do  model_listview

if (objComanda.getImprimir().equals("NO")) 
   { btnAnotacoes.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); } 
else { btnAnotacoes.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);  }

    //noinspection deprecation
    ad = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.model_listview_comanda, db.cursorListagem, from, to);

    /**
     * habilita o click no item da lista
     */

    listview.setOnItemClickListener(TelaComandaActivity.this);
    listview.setAdapter(ad);

}
```

if possible I would like to know which command I have to use for onClick on that button inside the ListView.